# Ignore test based on navigator(pock framework)

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

I want to launch some test in chrome and other test in Firefox,

how do I mark this test using spock extension to ignore depends on navigator? is it posible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Geb?  More info is needed.

Comment: Yes I use Geb framework

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@IgnoreIf` or `@Requires` tag which is used whether the test case will run or not. So, based on that condition you can decide whether your case will launch chrome or firefox.

```
class SampleRequiresSpec extends Specification {

private static boolean isOsWindows() {
    System.properties['os.name'] == 'windows'
}

@IgnoreIf({ Boolean.valueOf(properties['spock.ignore.longRunning']) })
def "run spec if Java system property 'spock.ignore.longRunning' is not set or false"() {
    expect:
    true
}

@IgnoreIf({ Boolean.valueOf(env['SPOCK_IGNORE_LONG_RUNNING']) })
def "run spec if environment variable 'SPOCK_IGNORE_LONG_RUNNING' is not set or false"() {
    expect:
    true
}

@IgnoreIf({ javaVersion < 1.7 })
def "run spec if run in Java 1.7 or higher"() {
    expect:
    true
}

@IgnoreIf({ javaVersion != 1.7 })
def "run spec if run in Java 1.7"() {
    expect:
    true
}

@IgnoreIf({ isOsWindows() })
def "run only if run on non-windows operating system"() {
    expect:
    true
}
@Requires({ isOsWindows })
def 'should run only on Windows'() {
    expect:
    true
}
```

}